# removing unwanted elements from blogger page

Tags: html, iframe, embed, blogger

I'm trying to embed an iframe into the page called 'test' of my test blog - damianp1.blogspot.co.uk

I've removed a lot of the unwanted items from the page to make as much room as possible, but can't find the id's to remove the blue box which appears behind the iframe, and also can't get the iframe to fit into the white box with the grey border at the bottom.

Here is the code I've used up to now:

```
<style type="text/css">

.blog-pager, .footer, .post-footer, .feed-links, #Attribution1, .comments, .post-title, .sidebar
{ display:none !important;}
.main-inner .columns {position: relative; left: -205px; top 50px; width: 1305;padding-left:0 !
important;padding-right:0 !important;}

</style>
</b:if>
<style>]

</style>

<div class="post-outer" style="width:1100px;">
<div id="outerdiv" style="width: 1200px; overflow: hidden">
<iframe width="1300" style="position: relative; left: -190px; top: -34px" height="600" 
src="http://wildlife-ramblings.blogspot.co.uk/" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

Can someone please tell me how to get everything fitting together properly so that the iframe fills the page neatly?

Many thanks, Damian.

Comment: `the blue box which appears behind the iframe` `the white box with the grey border at the bottom` .... ... what? I cannot see what you are describing. http://jsfiddle.net/h4Pa9/show/

Comment: Hi, there are two boxes which are behind the embedded iframe - a blue box with rounded corners and a white box with rounded corners and a grey footer - it's easier to see if you scroll to the bottom. I either want to remove them, or alter their size that that the iframe fits into them. I also want the iframe to fit the page properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blue box behind the iframe is located here:

```
.post-outer {
background-color: #eef8f8;
border: solid 1px #e8e8e8;
```

To remove the blue box, you can hide ".post-outer" or:

```
background-color: transparent;
border: none;
```

Add "!important" where needed.

The white box behind the iframe is located here:

```
.main-outer {
```

To remove the border, remove:

```
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
```

**EDIT:** **(based on different format idea)**

If you're wanting to expand the blue and white portions, you have to expand the width of the blog to the same width or greater than that of the iframe. 
Click on "Template" > orange button that says "Customize".
On the page that loads click "Adjust Widths".

If you don't want to increase the whole blog width, you can use conditional tags to only effect that page. To only affect that specific page, find "/b:skin" and paste the follow code BELOW it:

```
 <b:if cond='data:blog.url == &quot;http://damianp1.blogspot.co.uk/p/test_6572.html&quot;'>
 <style>
 #Blog1 {
 width: 1200px !important;
 }
 </style>
 </b:if>
```

To expand the height of the white part, you will have to add a "height: 800px" or however high the iframe is (or 20px-40px more to extend it past the iframe).

Make sure you remove the 110% width on the .post-outer and whatever else edits you have done previously before the first answer.

**EDIT: Asked about better way of doing this:**

Inside the post page where you want the ifrmae, use this code:

```
<style>
html, body {
overflow-y: hidden;
} 

#iframe-wrapper {
height: 100%;
width:1100px;
position: fixed;
scroll: no;
margin: 0 auto;
left:0px;
right: 0px;
z-index:9999;
margin-top: -52px;
top: 0px
bottom: 0px;
}

#title-wrapper {
height:70%;
margin:0 auto;
width: fixed;
background-color:  white;
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
border-bottom:20px  white solid;
border-right:20px  white solid;
border-left:20px  white solid;
text-align:center;
border-radius:30px;
-moz-border-radius:  30px;
-webkit-border-radius:  30px; 
}

.blog-pager, .footer, .post-footer, .feed-links, #Attribution1, .comments, .post-title, .sidebar
{ display:none !important;}
</style>

<div id="iframe-wrapper"><div id="iframe-inner">
</div><div id="title-wrapper"><h3><span style="color: black; font-size: 30px">Wildlife Ramblings</span></h3>

<div style="border: solid #e8e8e8 1px; padding: 20px; background: #eef8f8; border-radius:20px; -moz-border-radius:  20px; -webkit-border-radius: 20px; height: 83%"><embed  src="http://wildlife-ramblings.blogspot.co.uk/" width="100%" height="100%"></embed></div>
</div></div>
```

This will put the iframe over the blog itself (but with the same blog style containing the blue and white backgrounds with round corners), only on the page you paste the code in. Perhaps this will be easier for you.

You may need to adjust the positioning of the iframe by changing part of the code shown above. Find this part of the code:

```
#iframe-wrapper {
margin-top: -52px;
}
```

To move the whole iframe up (closer to the top of the page), increase the -52px to -62px (or whatever).  To move the whole iframe down (closer to the bottom of the page) decrease the -52px to -42px or whatever.

That should be the only part of the code that needs adjusting.

This a snapshot of what the above code should look like when you copy and paste it within the your blogger page:
[image: snapshot of what iframe code looks like]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've almost got it sorted! I've decided to put the iframe within the .post-outer and .main-outer boxes instead of deleting them. I've used this code....main-outer .post-outer  {width: 100%; float: left;  !important;}

Comment: ....I've used this code...  
    .main-outer  {width: 100%; float: left;  !important;}
 to try and make them bigger,  but it doesn't seem to effect their width. The only code that I've found that seems to effect them is... 
    .columns {width: 111%; float: left;  !important;} which expands the blue .post-outer box but doesn't expand the white .main-outer box. It's doing my head in!
http://damianp1.blogspot.co.uk/p/test_6572.html

Comment: I added the new edits to my answer above. If this works for you, click the check-mark below my answer. It will help me out :)

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your help. I just tried this, but it says - " A skin cannot contain the element: b:if. Only text and CDATA sections are accepted." Is there anyway to independently alter the width of the two boxes from within the code of the page itself? I tried to click the check mark under your name but nothing seemed to happen?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say was BELOW the "/b:skin"

Comment: Hi, i've just tried that and it doesn't seem to effect anything. I've tried increasing the 1200px to 2000px but it still made no difference. I removed all the editing in the page itself except for the iframe lines and it still doesn't seem to do anything. I seem to have solved the problem (see above) but I'm not sure how good a solution that is. Do you know why your solution isn't working? I'd rather do it your way with the conditional argument for that page if possible. Cheers, Damian.

Comment: I assumed the sidebar was still "display:none". I didn't mean for you to delete all your previous edits, just the ones where you mentioned about the 111% that you tried after my first answer.

Comment: Your below result is fine, just wrap it in the conditional tag. And add "margin: 0 auto !important" to center it (add it under the "#Blog1..." part.  #Blog1 {
 width: 1100px !important; margin: 0 auto !important;
 }

Comment: Try the edit I added, below the other 2 edits that you already tried. Let me know if that method works better for you.

Comment: Just tried the above and it looks awesome!! Thanks so much. One day I'll understand what you've done. I really appreciate the time you've spent on this and will try and click on your reputation thing. Thanks again, Damian.

Comment: No problem, delighted it worked for you. Thanks for clicking the check-mark. Also, I keep an eye on questions with the tag "Blogger" so if you need help with Blogger in the future, ask a question with that tag again. All the Best! :)

Comment: Thanks very much again Nik, if you want to see the finished result, the blog is now up and running - sthelensbirds.blogspot.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

Using your help from the above posts, I've just tried this within the html of the page itself and it seems to work...

```
<style type="text/css">

.blog-pager, .footer, .footer-outer, .post-footer, #sidebar-wrapper, #midsidebar-
wrapper, .gapad2, .post-header-line-1, .navbar, .feed-links, #Attribution1, .comments, 
.post-title, .sidebar { display:none !important;}

#Blog1 { width: 1100px; !important; } .main-outer { width: 1170px !important; }

</style>
</b:if>
<style>]
</style>

<iframe src="http://wildlife-ramblings.blogspot.co.uk/" style= border:3px #eef8f8 
solid;" name="Wildlife Ramblings" scrolling="yes" frameborder="1" marginheight="5px" 
marginwidth="5px" height="800px" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Here is the result... http://damianp1.blogspot.co.uk/p/test_5.html

I'm not sure how good a solution that is, but it's the best I've found so far. I wish I understood this instead of just faffing around with different code! Are there any better ways of doing this?

Thanks again, Damian.